# MySQL: How to speed up this query (incl. subqueries)?

Tags: mysql, subquery, database-performance

The index-page of my forum looks like this:

```
| Forum   | Topics | Answers |
 ----------------------------
| Forum A | 123    | 45678   | 
| Forum B | 345    | 23128   |
| Forum C | 567    |  2328   |
```

Here's my SQL code that works so far but I think there must be a better solution:

```
SELECT f.`id`, f.`name`, f.`description`, f.`type`, 

      (SELECT COUNT(`id`) 
         FROM threads 
        WHERE `forum_id` = f.`id`) AS num_threads, 

      (SELECT COUNT(p.`id`) 
         FROM threads t, posts p 
        WHERE p.thread_id = t.id 
          AND t.forum_id = f.id) AS num_posts 

  FROM `forums` f ORDER BY `position`
```

How would you speed up this query? Any alternatives to subqueries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, joining the basic select with a couple of subqueries with group by clauses (so they are executed once each, rather than once each per row)

```
  SELECT f.id, f.name, f.description, f.type, tc.RowCnt, ta.RowCnt
  FROM `forums` f 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT forum_id, COUNT(id) AS RowCnt FROM threads GROUP BY forum_id) tc
  INNER JOIN (SELECT forum_id, COUNT(p.id) AS RowCnt FROM threads t INNER JOIN posts p ON p.thread_id = t.id GROUP BY forum_id) ta
  ORDER BY position
```

You could likely improve this by doing one of the counts in the main select rather than the subselect (but it is late friday and I am tired!).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work - error: #1054 - Unknown column 'tc.RowCnt' in 'field list'

Comment: Whoops, forgot to put the alias names in the subselects

Answer (score 2):

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT   f.id, f.name, f.description, f.type, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS num_threads,
         COUNT(*) AS num_posts
FROM     forums f
    JOIN threads t ON  t.forum_id = f.id
    JOIN posts   p ON p.thread_id = t.id
GROUP BY f.id
ORDER BY f.position
```

Also, ensure that you have the following indexes:

- `(id)` on `forums`
- `(id, forum_id)` on `threads`
- `(thread_id)` on `posts`

(MySQL will require you to have these indexes if you have created [foreign key contraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The indexes exist but your code doesn't work as it should. I just get one result, but I see no limit in your SQL.